# Where does a published RDL file sit?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, rdl

When publishing a reporting services report. Where does the actual .RDL file sit on the server?

I can redownload the .RDL file via browsing through the report manager? But where is this file situated on the reporting services server?

Thanks

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It is not a file on the server. It stored as a BLOB in the ReportServer database.

(In the Catalog table to be precise on SSRS 2005)

[Extended Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17991798/6868683)

Answer (score 31):

This page shows how to retrieve this using T-SQL

http://mscrmuk.blogspot.com/2009/05/reading-rdl-definitions-directly-from.html

Jeff

**Update**: here's the relevant query, in case that blog post disappears in the future:

```
select convert(varchar(max), convert(varbinary(max), content))
from catalog
where content is not null
```

Comment: `catalog` is located in the ReportDatabase for SSRS inside SQL server.

Comment: btw, I tried this on sql server 2008r2 and I got a blank column.

Comment: This is awesome! I had to locate dependant reports for a table and above logic combined with a LIKE saved me many mins and hrs of effort. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that varchar(max) can return gigabytes worth of data, so the results in the SSMS results grid may not show the entire RDL content.  I had to right click on the column and choose 'Save Results As...' to get the whole RDL.

Comment: Is there any way to add a new URL link which will redirect to a new web page from the SSRS location? Kind of a link to new application from SSRS location itself?

Answer (score 7):

Following query specifically provide the report's blob

```
 SELECT Name, convert (varchar(max), convert (varbinary(max),[Content])) AS ReportRDL
 FROM [dbo].[Catalog] where TYPE =2
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to achieve this is open the report in Report Builder. Then click on file -> save as, then save it in the desired location.

Another way, When you open the report URL in the Internet Explorer,on hovering the report you'll see a drop down and there is an option to download the report.

Hope this helps.