# Where are my reports?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdl, reportmanager

I can see the SSRS reports via the Report Manager in the browser.  I know what database server it's pointing to.

How do I find where the source .rdl files are kept?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source file is stored in the **ReportServer** database of the SSRS instance you're looking at.

See [Report Server Database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156016%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in Books Online:

> The report server database is a SQL Server database that stores the
>   following content:
>
> Items managed by a report server (reports and linked reports, shared
>   data sources, report models, folders, resources) and all of the
>   properties and security settings that are associated with those items.

You can download these RDL files through Report Manager.

In SSRS 2008 you will need to go to the report **Properties** and choose **Edit** -> **Report Definition**.

For SSRS 2008R2, you can just choose **Download** from the report's dropdown.

See [Download \ Export RDL files from Report Server](http://sql-articles.com/blogs/download-export-rdl-files-from-report-server/) for more explicit details.

Comment: I cannot download at aIl. I am getting this error  'LinkedReport' is not allowed for this item type.