# Reverse Publish from SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

Using VS2017 with SSDT and an Report Project (as part of a larger solution) with git (via Bit Bucket) we are able to create/edit commit and publish SSRS reports fine. The new twist is we have a 'power user' who needs to be able to update reports using "Report Builder" (we are NOT going to give him VS).

Is there a way to 'Reverse Publish' changes that he might make to a report to get those changes back into VS (and then git)? (preferably in an automated fashion.)

Comment: Powershell maybe? http://www.sqlmusings.com/2011/03/28/how-to-download-all-your-ssrs-report-definitions-rdl-files-using-powershell/

Comment: Maybe...but really looking for something that already exists to handle this. Powershell would be a good possibility if there isn't an established pattern for doing this.

Comment: You could just give him bit bucket and restrict permissions to the reports you want him edit. He can use GIT/BB to check out files and edit them in the same way you are doing via VS and then he can check changes back in once he's done.

Comment: SSRS/Report Builder does not 'by default' actually create a 'document' that lives on the filesystem, but rather it stores the '.rdl' document in an sql table in the report server db. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914370/where-does-a-published-rdl-file-sit)